# cant break jquery function when there is ajax post

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
var id = $("input#user_id").val();

if (id != "") {
   $.post("function.php?act=check_id", { id: id }, function(data) {     
       if (data == "error") {                    
           return false;
       }
   });
   //some other codes going on here....
```

As you can see i am trying to break the function up to data coming from ajax post but it keeps going on other codes. i mean `return false` doesnt break it.

where am i wrong ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an asynchronous call, so it won't work as you intended it to - the check and return false will be run when data comes back from server, but the rest of the code will run anyway.  You should try jQuery.ajax with async = false if you want to wait for the result, or put other code inside the function given to post.

```
$.post("function.php?act=check_id", { id: id }, function(data) {        
  if (data != "error") {
    // some other code
  }
});
```

Comment: i think this is the best solution for me, thanks for all answers

Comment: @Ahmet - Yes, this would be a sensible approach, though since the return value is just ignored, you might as well get rid of the `return false;` part of the `if()` and just do `if(data != "error") { //run my code...`.

Answer (score 2):

The code beneath needs to go inside the `$.post()` function, as that gets executed on return.  The code after the AJAX call gets executed before it returns.

AJAX = **Asynchronous** JavaScript And XML

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want the AJAX calls to be synchronous, which can be done but still leaving the default setting of asynchronous is probably best and handling code when the ajax call is finished through the call back methods (ie completed, success, error handlers).  Basically if you make the AJAX call synchronous you will not know how long the request will take, which will lock the browser until the request returns.  This can be very undesirable for large AJAX requests.

**Some reference to jQuery AJAX calls**

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

**How to make AJAX run synchronously for all AJAX calls**

```
$.ajaxSetup({async:false});
```

**How to make AJAX run synchronously for one AJAX call**

```
$.ajax({
  async: false,
  type: 'POST',
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success
  dataType: dataType
});
```

Comment: can i make it just for specific post or for all posts in the page ?

Comment: This is so weird. ...[A]jax calls to be synchronous.

Comment: Note that if you make your call synchronous, the entire page will wait until the call returns; the user may experience a "frozen" browser page.

Comment: @ahmet vardar  Read the jQuery Documentation on ajax requests.  I provided a link for you in my answer.

Comment: @scottm - Strangely, AJAX calls don't need to be Asynchronous and don't need to return XML. The actual object being created is an XMLHTTPRequest, which is also a bit of a misnomer since HTTP is not a requirement either.

Comment: Whilst you can make calls synchronous, good point from Mr Hartsock.  Usually you would not want to, it freezes the page as the others state, most likely you want to continue with your code in a synchronous fashion without locking up the page.  You do this by placing that code in the handler event.

Comment: @patrick dw - I am aware, I just think that if this is the approach you are taking, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: @scottm - Ok, I see what you were getting at, and I'd tend to agree.

Answer (score 1):

You're making an asynchronous AJAX call. The code you're trying to prevent with the `return false;` executes long before the response returns.

Any code whose execution (or lack thereof) relies on the response from the AJAX call needs to be placed *inside* the callback (or placed in a function that is executed by the callback).